# How to find the port used by sshd for a port bind without sudo?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, pid, kill-process

To remove a given port bind the `pid` can be found with `sudo netstat -lnpt` and then removed with `kill pid`. As the process name is known (sshd) the non sudoer user who started it may found the pid with :

```
$ ps --user user -o pid,comm | grep sshd
8543 sshd
```

And then kill it. So port bind removal can be easily automatized for a non sudoer user.
 However if there are several port binds started by user, previous command will return several pids for several `sshd` processes . If user needs to remove only one given port bind, it needs to find which pid is listening to that port.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for the answer. Most of the system files can be read by any user so if you simply run:

```
less /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

you should be able to read the file. It should have something like `Port 22`, which is the port that SSH is listening on.

Port 22 is the default port for SSH, so if the line is commented (`#Port 22`), then its listening on Port 22 as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tectia you can check ssh-server listening port using below command:

```
grep "port" < /etc/opt/SSHtectia/ssh-server-config.xml
```

If there are multiple ssh-server processes and each is listening on different port you can check for each process which port is listening using below command:

```
ps -ef | grep "ssh-server"
```